# How to show image in crystal report using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using vb.net ( visual studio 2012).
I have a form that contains a datagridview , an image and a button print.
I want when i click on the button the data in the datagridview and the image will be shown in the crystal report viewer.
I created data table and add all the fields including the image ( with the type bytes).
Now when i click on the button print the datagridview fields are showen but the image is not shown 
 Does some one could hep me with a code or with a step-by-step method to show the image ? 
The image is not imported from database. It's from a local file.
Thank you

Comment: You say that that the database includes `the image ( with the type bytes)` but then say the `Image is not imported from database. It's from a local file.` Which is it? Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you Alexander. But the image is not imported from a database it's from a local file